# Flurry integration error in android

Tags: android, flurry

I have implemented Flurry SDK for Android but getting an error in logcat:

```
E/FlurryAgent: Ad server responded with the following error(s):
    Adunit name or code provided in the request is invalid.
```

I have written these code in onStart

```
FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this);
        adView.fetchAndDisplayAd();
```

I have no idea what went wrong. I added right api key but still getting same error again and again.

Note: I integrated it couple of hours ago. Is it only taking time to initialize or it's really an error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the ad unit name you use in your ad call is not matching an available ad unit in your account. Make sure the ad unit name you specify in your ad setup:

```
mFlurryAdNative = new FlurryAdNative(this, mAdSpaceName);
```

or

```
mFlurryAdInterstitial = new FlurryAdInterstitial(this, mAdSpaceName);
```

or

```
mFlurryAdBanner = new FlurryAdBanner(this, mBanner, mAdSpaceName);
```

matches the ad unit name you created in the Flurry portal, using the steps here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/gettingstarted/basicadunitsetup

Comment: I have already added those. I found the problem. My ad space name was wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is this Ads Space name.. i didn't find in Flurry monetization.. Meanwhile i get same error "Adunit name or code provided in the request is invalid."

Comment: Click the monetization tab on the left, then "Apps & Ad Units". Click to expand the ad units for the app in question, and the ad unit name is the left-most column.